# DataTable.Merge throws Error: Object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, merge, datatable

I want to merge datatables in the DropDownList selectedindex changed event. So I have written the below code in the DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged Event.

```
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)POBLL.GetPOAdhocDetail();
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = "IndentTypeID = " + ddlIndentType.SelectedValue + "AND IndentID = " + ddlIndentNumber.SelectedValue;
    DataTable dtView = dv.ToTable();        
    gvPODetails.DataSource = dtView;
    gvPODetails.DataBind();
    DTMerge.Merge(dtView);
```

where DTMerge is the DataTable and I declared it like below:

```
   public DataTable DTMerge
   {
      get
      {
        if (ViewState["Merge"] != null)
        {
            return (DataTable)ViewState["Merge"];
        }
        else
            return null;
      }
      set
      {
         ViewState["Merge"] = value;
      }
  }
```

But it throws the Error "Object reference not set to an instance". How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You requested DTMerge property, which for being valid need of presence of corresponding ViewState. You don't have a ViewState yet, at the moment you access DTMerge property.

This is most likely the problem.

Comment: But I want to Merge the same Datatable for each SelectedindexChanged Event. How to do this?

Comment: If DTMerge is null, make it equal to dt: DTMerge = dt; if not, cobtinue what you do.